# Computer freezes during NIntegrate[]

Tags: numerical-integration, system-performance

I have a notebook that freezes the computer every time I run it (I mean the whole computer becomes unresponsive and do not react to ctrl-shift-esc and ctr-alt-delete as well as alt-tab and windows-tab). The weird thing is it used to work without any big differences in the code as far as I can remember. I have made sure that it is indeed the notebook that freezes the computer. Here is the code:

```
t1 = 1.696222702113381;
p1 = 5.604730078805160;
t2 = 1.439432831934896;
p2 = 2.373727848568306;

psiN2[a_, b_, t1_, p1_, t2_, p2_, k_, n_, twoS_] := 
  Cos[a/2]^k*Sin[a/2]^(n - 1 - k)*
   Exp[I*(k - (n - 1)/2)*
     b]*((Cos[a/2]*Cos[t1/2]*Exp[I*(p1 - b)/2] + 
        Sin[a/2]*Sin[t1/2]*Exp[I*(b - p1)/2])^
      twoS + (Cos[a/2]*Cos[t2/2]*Exp[I*(p2 - b)/2] + 
        Sin[a/2]*Sin[t2/2]*Exp[I*(b - p2)/2])^twoS);

PsiN2[a1_, b1_, a2_, b2_, t1_, p1_, t2_, p2_, k1_, k2_, n_, twoS_] := 
  Det[{{psiN2[a1, b1, t1, p1, t2, p2, k1, n, twoS], 
     psiN2[a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, k1, n, twoS]}, {psiN2[a1, b1, t1, 
      p1, t2, p2, k2, n, twoS], 
     psiN2[a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, k2, n, twoS]}}];


NIntegrate[
 Abs[PsiN2[a1, b1, a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, 0, 1, 1, 3]]^2*Sin[a1]*
  Sin[a2], {a1, 0, Pi}, {b1, 0, 2*Pi}, {a2, 0, Pi}, {b2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

It's the numerical integration above that causes the freeze. I realize that it is a big calculation, but as mentioned it used to work (although it took a long time, around 30-60 minutes).

My specs are: Mathematica 10 on windows 7 with 4 cores and 20 GB of memory. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: When you say it used to take a long time, give us a clue? A minute, an hour or a day :)

Comment: Around 30-60 minutes I'd say.

Comment: When you say your computer freezes, you mean other applications become unresponsive and you have to reboot?  OR just that Mathematica itself is busy?

Comment: I mean the whole computer freezes and I have to reboot by means of holding the off button for a while (ctrl-shift-esc and ctr-alt-delete as well as alt-tab and windows-tab are unresponsive).

Comment: Does this freeze happen as soon as you start the calculation off or sometime after?

Comment: You're probably going to say sometime after when your machine chewed all the way through its 20Gb memory.  I have 16Gb on my machine and it became sluggish when the kernel passed 12Gb though I have other stuff going on too.  So the question "why does this calculation burn through so much memory?" remains.

Comment: Ok! A very handwavy answer to that could be that it's a complicated 4-dimensional integral.. I guess another question is why does it chew so much memory that it freezes when a code with "trivial changes" didn't (this is very vague I admit. Maybe it's time to lay this question dead..)

Comment: I have had similar experience! I use task manager to keep track of this. Sometimes, Mathematica uses memory suddenly jump from 200MB to 3.9GB in less than 30 seconds. That freezed my laptop as well. I have to force the kernel to close immediately, to avoid system crush. Mine specs: i7 940X, 4G, Win 7 X64, MMA 10 X64.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integrand goes to infinity along `a1 == 0` and `a2 == 0`:

```
Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  Abs[PsiN2[a1, b1, a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, 0, 1, 1, 3]]^2 * Sin[a1] * Sin[a2],
  {a1, 0, Pi}, {a2, 0, Pi}],
 {b1, 0, 2*Pi}, {b2, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can see the divergence of the integral by controlling `MaxRecursion`:

```
Table[Quiet@
  NIntegrate[
   Abs[PsiN2[a1, b1, a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, 0, 1, 1, 3]]^2*Sin[a1]*
    Sin[a2], {a1, 0, Pi}, {b1, 0, 2*Pi}, {a2, 0, Pi}, {b2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
   MaxRecursion -> r],
 {r, 2, 5}]
(*
{6.67053*10^6 + 0. I,
 1.06724*10^8 + 0. I,
 1.70758*10^9 + 0. I, 
 2.73213*10^10 + 0. I}
*)
```

The kind of recursive subdivision that `NIntegrate` does quickly explodes the number of function evaluations in a high-dimensional integral, which in this case approaches a 16-fold increase in memory usage at each subdivision:

```
Table[MaxMemoryUsed[
  Quiet@NIntegrate[
    Abs[PsiN2[a1, b1, a2, b2, t1, p1, t2, p2, 0, 1, 1, 3]]^2*Sin[a1]*
     Sin[a2], {a1, 0, Pi}, {b1, 0, 2*Pi}, {a2, 0, Pi}, {b2, 0, 2*Pi}, 
    MaxRecursion -> r]
  ],
 {r, 2, 5}]
N @ Ratios[%]
(*
  {618704, 4407384, 64871808, 1032170480}
  {7.12357, 14.7189, 15.9109}
*)
```